# Django Context Syntax

Tags: django

I am getting a syntax error in my context:

> 'meta_description':meta_description
>
> The arrow points the the colon.

Here is my view which gives me the error:

Comment: You missed the , (comma)  in `'meta_keywords':meta_keywords` ( context dict )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot , after meta_keywords

```
        context = {
            'c':c,
            'menuitems':menuitems,
            'page_title':page_title,
            'meta_keywords':meta_keywords,
            'meta_description':meta_description
            }
```